# Checking MySQL DB connectivity with Spring Boot JPA - how to set the timeout of Hikari

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

My Spring Boot app is using a `MySQL` DB and I like to add a check in order to know if the app can reach the DB or not. Something like:

```
Select 1 From Cats
```

The app uses JPA in order to connect to the DB and perform the different business logic needs:

```
public interface CatRepository extends CrudRepository<Cat, Long>{
      // nothing here at the moment
}

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Since in `CrudRepository` there is nothing similar to `ping`, I'm using the `count()` method:

```
 public boolean isDBReachable(){
    long count = catRepository.count();
    return true;
}
```

So when the DB is not reachable, the following exception is thrown:

```
ERROR [o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] - HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms.
```

I like to change the timeout from 30 seconds to 5 seconds. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this [post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hikari) the solution was to update the yml file of the app:

```
spring:
  datasource:
     hikari:
         connection-timeout: 5000
```